# ASP MVC 2: Regular expression attribute working on clientside but not on serverside

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$", ErrorMessage="Date is not valid must be like (dd/mm/jjjj)")]
public DateTime Startdate{ get; set;}
```

The client-side validation works perfectly. So it seems that JavaScript can successfully understand my regular expression. But when I do a postback, and the modelstate.Isvalid() gets called.

My date isn't valid anymore. So I'm guessing that when .NET performs the matching with the regEx it doesn't match.

My question: Why does this regular expression match on the client side but not on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is becouse when you do postback databinder goes first, and it could not parse value to DateTime. 
By the way it's not a good idea to put RegularExpression attribute on DateTime class. It has following code

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    string str = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    Match match = this.Regex.Match(str);
    return ((match.Success && (match.Index == 0)) && (match.Length == str.Length));
}
```

so Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) will never match your regex, becouse it will have time part too.

You should better use String instead of datetime.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to check regular expression, you should use:

```
public string Startdate{ get; set;}
```

and then convert it to `DateTime` on server side, after model binding. You know that date has to be provided in specific format, but model binder is not that smart and throws an error. If you have `DateTime` after model binding, there is no sense in checking it by regular expression, doesn't it? Model binding comes first and then validation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the client-side validation rules aren't actually being applied? Have you checked that the required attribute works as expected? You should be able to use firebug to double-check that the regular expression is the same on the server side, that all values are as expected etc.

Also - it could be that the inserted value passes the regex, but still can't be converted to a datetime by the model binder - that would also produce a model error.

I haven't checked your regex to see what it really does, but if you're trying to verify that the input is a valid date, use the `DataTypeAttribute` instead.

Comment: I tried the datatypeAttribute, It doesn't validate at all. I also read on the internet that it is not made for validation.